# spartacus sampledata inconsistency: spartacus requests "shipping-address" but in 2105 sampledata there is only "delivery-address"-> Checkout broken

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have setup the current version of spartacus (4.3) with Sap Commerce 2205 according to the installation instructions.
No customizations have been done to backend or frontend.
I observe the following issue when trying to enter the checkout in electronics and apparel store:

The request just is being sent in an endless loop **because the stroefront requests "shipping-address" which does not exist.**
**Only "delivery-address" exists.** Even when changing the page label of the contentpage to "shipping-address" so that the request from teh frontend can be fulfilled, the checkout page just remains empty and is not functional.

Any ideas what can be done to fix this ootb error?

[Image with the endless loop requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1xoj.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after some more research, i can answer this myself:

The naming in the impex files in the sampledata for 2105 (the most current sampledata) has been changed from "shipping" to "delivery".
But the spartacus frontend (still) asks for and expects a page with "shipping"-label and "shipping"-components.

A workaround is to go through the files in the sampledata and adjust delivery to shipping where necessary and import the relevant lines in the backend.

Would be great if SAP fixes this inconsistency to not throw off people setting up the system according to the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the specific changes need to get it working for me are as follows - for electronics content catalog.  The other catalogs require similar changes.

Source file: spartacussampledata/import/contentCatalogs/electronicsContentCatalog/cms-responsive-content.impex

- ContentPage.label : /checkout/delivery-address -> /checkout/shipping-address
- CMSFlexComponent.flexType : CheckoutDeliveryAddress -> CheckoutShippingAddress

```
$contentCatalog=electronics-spaContentCatalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Online])[default=$contentCatalog:Online]
INSERT_UPDATE ContentPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;masterTemplate(uid,$contentCV);label;defaultPage[default='true'];approvalStatus(code)[default='approved'];homepage[default='false']
;;CheckoutDeliveryAddress;Checkout Delivery Address Page;MultiStepCheckoutSummaryPageTemplate;/checkout/shipping-address
INSERT_UPDATE CMSFlexComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;flexType
;;CheckoutDeliveryAddressComponent;Checkout Delivery Address Component;CheckoutShippingAddress
```